# Regular Expressions - Select all before first whitespace character assuming it includes both characters and digits

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I've built a little Google Maps widget to speed up the process of people inputting their address into a form, however, because it seems Google Maps isn't particularly accurate when it comes to actual house numbers, I've added the ability to override / prepend a house number to the selected location.

Here's a quick example...

I select a location on the map and it returns:
`13B Main Street, London, L0N D0N, United Kingdom`

Which is great, however, assuming the person filling out the form doesn't live at 13B but 13A, I'm trying to use a regular expression to override / replace this section of the string.

I currently have the following: `/([^\s]+)/` which selects the first word or all until the first white space character which again worked fine, until I noticed that Google Maps sometimes doesn't return an building number meaning `Main Street` would become `REPLACED Street` if no building number is returned.

So basically, I'm trying to build a regular expression that meets the following conditions.

> It's the first word (before any whitespace character) and
>   it must either be solely a number or a combination of both not just characters.

Thanks for any help!

*Also, if it's not too much to ask if you're posting the answer could you perhaps explain slightly how the regular expression is constructed and which parts are checking for what. Thanks!*

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex to match only part of text that must contain a digit before first whitespace:

```
/^[a-zA-Z]*\d[a-zA-Z\d]*(?=\s)/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dX6lH9/1)

Answer (score 0):

This regex

`/^(^\d+\w*\s)/`

Will match any number of digits (at least one) followed by any number of word characters (including zero) at the start of a line, followed by a space. Up to you whether to include the space in the match

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dX6lH9/2)

Comment: Unlike the answer that @anubhava gives, mine will insist on house numbers starting with a number, so won't match "a1"

Answer (score 0):

One idea is `/^\s*[\w-]*\d+[\w-]*/` it will take care of previous white spaces, and address forms such as D12, 12D, D-12 or 12-C